# I need help (haskell) inhabitant for the type

Tags: haskell

Last Friday my teacher give me this problem:

Give an inhabitant for the type

```
(a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
```

and i do not understand exactly what it asks for

EDIT:Exercise completed. The given type corresponds with the default haskell flip function. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 5):

"Inhabitant of a type" means an expression which has some given type. For instance, `2` is an inhabitant of `Int`, and `["Foo","Bar"]` is an inhabitant of `[String]`.

In other words, your teacher is asking you to write something that has a type `(a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c`.

I won't solve this for you since it's homework, but if you're having trouble writing such a function, your first step would be to write out all the arguments and their types, then try to use them together to complete it.